# Display flash video in irregular quadrilateral shape

Tags: flash, actionscript, graphics, macromedia

I'm a novice to Flash and I've been trying unsuccessfully to display video with defined irregular dimensions (practically a quadrilateral with various edge size). Would that be possible?

I see that there are only several customization options:
1. positioning in a plane defined by (x,y) that corresponds to the position of the top left corner of the video.
2. width and height.

If it's not possible in flash, are there any other options with programmable features like that of flash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found one amazing implementation here: http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=218

Answer (score 2):

You can apply [Matrix](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/Matrix.html) transformations to all `DisplayObject`s in Flash.